# How viewable attribute works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Can you tell me how this "viewable" works and what is it? I don't get it... 
In Product model we have **two** relationships with the same `:as => :viewable` parameter. I found only one place with `viewable` - there's a `viewable_id` in `assets` table.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :image, :as => :viewable
  has_many :contents, :as => :viewable
end


class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :viewable, :polymorphic => true
end

class CreateAssets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :assets do |t|
      t.string :viewable_type
      t.integer :viewable_id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic polymorphic relationship. Details are on the [Active Record Association Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) page of the Rails Guide but it simple terms it means that the Assets table will store multiple different types of asset-like objects.

The Product model is declaring two types of Asset. One Image and many Contents objects. The Assets table will be used to store details on both these types, i.e. you won't have a separate Images table and a Contents table.

The viewable_id in Assets will be a foreign key to the id of the Product. The viewable_type will indicate whether the Asset is an Image or a Content object.